# Scala type error

Tags: scala, math, jvm

I'm working on a Hacker Rank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/eval-ex) and I got a bit stuck.

I have an exception that keeps coming up:

```
Solution.scala:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Double, Double) => Double
 required: (AnyVal, AnyVal) => AnyVal
                (1 to 9).reduce((total: Double, current: Double) => Math.pow(exp,current)/factNonRecursive(current))
```

What am I doing wrong in this Scala code?

Full Code:

```
object Solution {
def factNonRecursive(num: Double): Double = {
     (1 to (num.toInt)).foldLeft(1) ((a,b) => (a * b)) toDouble
  }
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val sc = new java.util.Scanner (System.in);
        var n = sc.nextInt();
        var a0 = 1;
        while(a0 < n){
            var x = sc.nextDouble();
            def e(exp: Double) = {
                (1 to 9).reduce((total: Double, current: Double) => Math.pow(exp,current)/factNonRecursive(current))
            }
            println(e(x))
            a0+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you have a `Range[Int]`, which you later call `reduce` on and it expects an `Int`, not a `Double`, hence the compiler is inferring the common ancestor type for both which is `AnyVal`. You'll need to `map` the integers to doubles first:

```
(1 to 9)
  .map(_.toDouble)
  .reduce((_, current) => Math.pow(exp, current) / factNonRecursive(current))
```

Another approach, instead of `Range`, would be to use `List.range(1.0, 9.0)` and avoid the additional `map`:

```
List.range(1.0, 9.0)
  .reduce((_, current) => Math.pow(exp, current) / factNonRecursive(current))
```

Additionally, `factNonRecursive` can be substituted with `product`:

```
(1 to num.toInt).product.toDouble
```

Comment: You are the greatest.